# Feature importance in neural networks with multiple differently shaped inputs in pytorch and captum (classification)

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, embedding

I have developed a model with three inputs types. Image, categorical data and numerical data. For Image data I've used ResNet50 for the other two I develop my own network.

```py
class MulticlassClassification(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, cat_size, num_col, output_size, layers, p=0.4):
        super(MulticlassClassification, self).__init__()
        
        # IMAGE: ResNet
        self.cnn = models.resnet50(pretrained = True)
        for param in self.cnn.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False
        n_inputs = self.cnn.fc.in_features
        self.cnn.fc = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Linear(n_inputs, 250), 
          nn.ReLU(), 
          nn.Dropout(p),
          nn.Linear(250, output_size),                   
          nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
        )
        
        # TABULAR 
        self.all_embeddings = nn.ModuleList(
            [nn.Embedding(categories, size) for categories, size in cat_size]
        )
        self.embedding_dropout = nn.Dropout(p)
        self.batch_norm_num = nn.BatchNorm1d(num_col)

        all_layers = []
        num_cat_col = sum(e.embedding_dim for e in self.all_embeddings)
        input_size = num_cat_col + num_col

        for i in layers:
            all_layers.append(nn.Linear(input_size, i))
            all_layers.append(nn.ReLU(inplace=True))
            all_layers.append(nn.BatchNorm1d(i))
            all_layers.append(nn.Dropout(p))
            input_size = i

        all_layers.append(nn.Linear(layers[-1], output_size))

        self.layers = nn.Sequential(*all_layers)
        
        #combine
        self.combine_fc = nn.Linear(output_size * 2, output_size)

    def forward(self, image, x_categorical, x_numerical):
        embeddings = []
        for i, embedding in enumerate(self.all_embeddings):
            print(x_categorical[:,i])
            embeddings.append(embedding(x_categorical[:,i]))
        x = torch.cat(embeddings, 1)
        x = self.embedding_dropout(x)

        x_numerical = self.batch_norm_num(x_numerical)
        x = torch.cat([x, x_numerical], 1)
        x = self.layers(x)
        
        # img
        x2 = self.cnn(image)
        
        # combine
        x3 = torch.cat([x, x2], 1)
        x3 = F.relu(self.combine_fc(x3))
        
        return x
```

Now after successful training I would like to calculate integrated gradients by using the captum library.

```py
from captum.attr import IntegratedGradients
ig = IntegratedGradients(model)

testiter = iter(testloader)
img, stack_cat, stack_num, target = next(testiter)
attributions_ig = ig.attribute(inputs=(img.cuda(), stack_cat.cuda(), stack_num.cuda()), target=target.cuda())
```

And here I got an error:

> RuntimeError: Expected tensor for argument #1 'indices' to have one of the following scalar types: Long, Int; but got torch.cuda.FloatTensor instead (while checking arguments for embedding)

I figured out that captum injects a wrongly shaped tensor into my x_categorical input (with the print in my forward method). It seems like captum only sees the first input tensor and uses it's shape for all other inputs. How can I change this behaviour?

I've found the similar issue here (https://github.com/pytorch/captum/issues/439). It was recommended to use Interpretable Embedding for categorical data. When I used it I got this error:

> IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)

I would be very grateful for any tips and advises how to combine all three inputs and to solve my problem.